# pdf editor or tool for analyze, measure and comment for linux (if unavoidable windows with wine)

Tags: linux, pdf, editor

I used Adobe Acrobat 7.0 for analyze(used font,fontsize), measure(margins,sizes, ...) and comment pdf files with Windows.

This old version is perfect for my needs, but i think this old version is a security risk today, because i need to check pdf files from untrusted sources.

I need a program like Acrobat 7.0 for Linux.
Regrettably Acrobat 7.0 is not stable enough with wine on ubuntu 17.10.

Which alternatives are there? 
a) for linux b) for windows compatible with linux wine

Answer (score 1):

You could try Xournal for highlighting, drawing, and typing notes onto the pdf.  Depending on the distro you can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install xournal
```

Also, i've never used it much but Okular should be able to do everything you need.

```
sudo apt-get install okular
```

Comment: @HeinBloed42 what do you mean by sh?